# Open a page in new tab and refresh the old page(Struts2 + javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

I am having one hidden form

```
<form name="printPhysicalAnn" id="printPhysicalAnn" method="post" target='_new'>

        <s:hidden name="aId" id="aId"/>
        <s:hidden name="ty" id="ty" value="physical possession"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="appId" id="appIdsss" value="${appId}"/>
    </form>
```

Which is being submitted through javascript. The resultant page opens in new tab. I want to refresh the parent tab after this form is submitted.  The following javascript code works perfectly fine all the browsers except Google Chrome.

```
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to generate certificate");
     if (r == true) {
        document.printPhysicalAnn.action = root+"/RES/ann2HsiidcPhysical";
         document.forms['printPhysicalAnn'].submit();
         document.location =window.location;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
document.location =window.location;
```

Use

```
location.reload();
```

or this if you want to bypass cache

```
location.reload(true);
```

Edit :

Your form isn't submitting because `_new` isn't a valid target. Use `_blank` if you want it to open in a new tab/window

Comment: If I use location.reload(); It only reloads the current page. but the page that was to be opened in the next tab does not open. Aprt from that I used the following code to fire the function which reloads the current page..But this code does'nt execute.     $('#printPhysicalAnn').on('submit', function () {
    alert('Form submitted!');
location.reload();
    return false;
});

Comment: Edited to answer this opening problem